# Create Symlink from recursive search in a certain folder

Tags: bash, for-loop, find, ln

I want to create **Symlinks** for a recursive `find` search.
This should also work for folders containing spaces.

The Symlinks should get created in a certain folder.

I tried to use this script:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for t in $(find . -type d -name "*search*" | sed 's|.*/||'); do
    ln -s "$t" "./symlink-folder/$t"
done
```

the problem is that the full path of the files does not get passed to `ln`, so the links created are all broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, seems like I made it running with:

```
cd ./symlink-folder/
find ../ -type d -name "*search*" -exec ln -s {} . ';'
```

it does work with spaces